# Insert data in Date Field of Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

HTML code Whole Page

```
 <html><head><title>BOSS</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE8; IE=EmulateIE9; IE=EmulateIE10; IE=EmulateIE11; ">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/css/ddsmoothmenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/css/MenuPage.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/scripts/jquery12/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/scripts/jquery12/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/scripts/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/scripts/clock.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/scripts/IframeStatus.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/scripts/tableEffects.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/scripts/Commonall.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/scripts/MenuPage.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var gLoginKey ='1633328062-01022071071078';
    var gLoginId ='103';
    function ShowMenus(pAppId)  
    {
        frmMain.AppId.value = pAppId;
        frmMain.submit();
        return;
    }


    function logout(e)
    {
            location.assign("/stocks/Logout?LoginKey=" + gLoginKey+ "&LoginId="+gLoginId+"&ScrId=0-100000000");
    }

    /*function loginLog()
    {
        parent.frames['frmmainsurv'].location.href="/stocks/LoginLog?LoginKey=" + gLoginKey+ "&LoginId="+gLoginId;
        return;
    }
    */
    function ChangePwd()
    {
        var w=window.open("/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/password.jsp?LoginKey=" + gLoginKey+ "&LoginId="+gLoginId+"&ScrId=0-100000005",'window1','scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=300,height=200');

    }
    function handleKey1(pEvent)
    {
        if(pEvent.keyCode == 116)
        {
            pEvent.keyCode=0;
            pEvent.returnValue=false;
            pEvent.cancelBubble=true;
        }
    }
    function Reload()
    {

        frmMain.AppId.value="-1";
        frmMain.submit();
    }

    function modelesswin(url,mwidth,mheight){
        var mLeft=screen.width-200;
        var mTop=screen.height-200;
        if (document.all&&window.print) //if ie5
        eval('window.showModelessDialog(url,"BSELINK","help:0;resizable:0;scrollbars:0;dialogTop='+mTop+';dialogLeft='+mLeft+';dialogWidth:'+mwidth+'px;dialogHeight:'+mheight+'px")');
        else
            eval('window.open(url,"BSELINK","width='+mwidth+'px,height='+mheight+'px,resizable=0,scrollbars=0")');
    }

    // added by nitish.kadam for check browser name.

    $(function(){
        var browserName = navigator.appName;
        if("Microsoft Internet Explorer"==browserName){
            $('#middle').css('margin-top',"10px");
        }
        else{
            $('#middle').css('margin-top',"0px");  
            $('#footerDetails').css('margin-top',"-10px");
    }
    });

    </script>
<style type="text/css">

    #header, #footer, #middle {

            width: 100%;
            left: 0;

        }

    #middle {
        /* top: 75px;
        bottom: 30px;
        overflow: auto ;*/
        top: 63px;
        position: fixed;

        overflow: auto;
        /* height: 550px; */
        width:99%;
        background: white;  
        /* border: solid #fe770f 1px; */
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        height: 88%;
        clear:both;
        z-index: 10;

    }

    #header {
        /* height: 80px; */
        height: 10%;
        top: 0;
        /* background:black; */
        border:0x solid #666;
        color: white;


    }
    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        height: 2%;
        bottom: 0;
        /* background:black; */
        border:0px solid #666;
        color: black;

    }


    #element1 {display:inline-block;} 
    #element2 {display:inline-block;} 

    #footerTdId1{
        width: 1%;
    }

    #footerTdId2{
        width: 90%;
    }

    iframe#frmmainsurv {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    </style>

    </head>

    <body oncontextmenu="return true;" style="height: 100%;overflow:hidden;width:100%"><!--Height added-->


    <div id="header "> <!-- added by nitish -->

        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td align="center" width="20%">
                    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:Reload();">

                    <img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/eboss.gif" height="55" border="0" alt="" style="z-index:-1">
                    </a>

                </td>

                <td align="left">
                    <div>

                        <div id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu" style="display:inline-block;">
                        <ul>




    <li style="z-index: 100;"><a href="#" class="" style="padding-right: 23px;">Alerts &amp; Events<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/down.gif" class="downarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="top: 30px; visibility: visible; left: 0px; width: 237px; display: none;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Views/NewsAnnouncements.jsp?ScrId=3-106');">News Announcements</a></li><li style="z-index: 99;"><a href="#" class="">Member Surveillance Alerts<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="top: 0px; visibility: visible; left: 237px; width: 237px; display: none;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberAlertsReport.jsp?ScrId=3-159');">Regulatory</a></li><li style="z-index: 98;"><a href="#" class="">Exchange<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="top: 0px; visibility: visible; left: 237px; width: 237px; display: none;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/DailyAlert_MemberEquity.jsp?ScrId=3-160');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/DailyAlert_MemberDer.jsp?ScrId=3-161');">Derivative</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/DailyAlert_MemberCurr.jsp?ScrId=3-405');">Currency</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/DailyAlert_MemberComm.jsp?ScrId=3-562');">Commodity</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberAlertBulkUpload.jsp?ScrId=3-612');">Member Regulatory Alert Response Upload</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/Inspection.jsp?ScrId=3-144');">Inspection And Compliance Checklist</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberWorkFlow.jsp?ScrId=3-157');">Workflow Statistics</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Views/DynamicPriceBands.jsp?ScrId=3-163');">Dynamic Price Band Scrips</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('RealtimeNews/NewsPlus.jsp?ScrId=3-241');">Realtime News</a></li><li style="z-index: 97;"><a href="#" class="">Member Dashboard<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberDashboard.jsp?ScrId=3-103');">Equity/Derivatives</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberDashboard_Curr.jsp?ScrId=3-543');">Currency</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberDashboard_Comm.jsp?ScrId=3-553');">Commodity</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 96;"><a href="#" style="padding-right: 23px;" class="">Member Mis<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/down.gif" class="downarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="top: 30px; visibility: visible; left: 0px; width: 237px; display: none;"><li style="z-index: 95;"><a href="#" class="">Member Scrip Client<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="top: 0px; visibility: visible; left: 237px; width: 237px; display: none;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MSCMainEquity.jsp?ScrId=3-137');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MSCMain.jsp?ScrId=3-138');">Derivative</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MSCMainCurr.jsp?ScrId=3-353');">Currency</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MSCMainComm.jsp?ScrId=3-560');">Commodity</a></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 94;"><a href="#">Self Trades<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/SelfTradesEquity.jsp?ScrId=3-140');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/SelfTrades.jsp?ScrId=3-141');">Derivative</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Charts/MemberCharts.jsp?ScrId=3-142');">Charts &amp; Analysis</a></li><li style="z-index: 93;"><a href="#">Marketwide Position Limits - Mwpl<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MwplAssetReport.jsp?ScrId=3-148');">Assetwise (Online)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MwplClientIndexFutures_MemberRpt.jsp?ScrId=3-149');">Clientwise(Online)</a></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 92;"><a href="#">Client Scrip<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/ClientScripMain.jsp?ScrId=3-155');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/ClientScripMainDerivative.jsp?ScrId=3-156');">Derivative</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/CSClientViewCurrMain.jsp?ScrId=3-354');">Currency</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/CSClientViewCommMain.jsp?ScrId=3-561');">Commodity</a></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 91;"><a href="#">Client Profit/Loss<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberClientProfitLossEquity.jsp?ScrId=3-181');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberClientProfitLossDerivative.jsp?ScrId=3-182');">Derivative</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/ClientDataReportMember.jsp?ScrId=3-185');">Client/Ucc Details </a></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 90;"><a href="#" style="padding-right: 23px;">Trades<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/down.gif" class="downarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 30px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/CurrencyTradeView.jsp?ScrId=3-355');">Currency</a></li><li style="z-index: 89;"><a href="#">Self Trades<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/right.gif" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/EquityTradeViewSelfTrades.jsp?ScrId=3-417');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/DerivativeTradeViewSelfTrades.jsp?ScrId=3-418');">Derivative</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/CurrencyTradeViewSelfTrades.jsp?ScrId=3-419');">Currency</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/CommodityTradeViewSelfTrades.jsp?ScrId=3-551');">Commodity</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/CommodityTradeViewMem.jsp?ScrId=3-550');">Commodity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/EquityTradeView.jsp?ScrId=3-91');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/DerivativeTradeView.jsp?ScrId=3-92');">Derivatives</a></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 88;"><a href="#" style="padding-right: 23px;">Orders<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/down.gif" class="downarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 30px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/OrderDataCurr.jsp?ScrId=3-356');">Currency</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/OrderDataComm.jsp?ScrId=3-552');">Commodity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/OrderDataEquity.jsp?ScrId=3-94');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/OrderDataDer.jsp?ScrId=3-95');">Derivatives</a></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 87;"><a href="#" style="padding-right: 23px;" class="">Top Gainers Losers<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/down.gif" class="downarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 30px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Views/CurrencyTopGainers.jsp?ScrId=3-358');">Currency</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Views/CommodityTopGainers.jsp?ScrId=3-558');">Commodity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/EquityTopGainer.jsp?ScrId=3-97');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Views/DerivativeTopGainers.jsp?ScrId=3-98');">Derivatives</a></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 86;"><a href="#" class="" style="padding-right: 23px;">Most Active By Volume/Value<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/down.gif" class="downarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="top: 30px; visibility: visible; left: 0px; width: 237px; display: none;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MostActiveByValue.jsp?ScrId=3-100');">Equity</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Views/MostActiveByValueDer.jsp?ScrId=3-101');">Derivatives</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Views/MostActiveByValueCurr.jsp?ScrId=3-359');">Currency</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Views/MostActiveByValueComm.jsp?ScrId=3-559');">Commodity</a></li></ul></li><li style="z-index: 85;"><a href="#" class="" style="padding-right: 23px;">User Management<img src="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/images/down.gif" class="downarrowclass" style="border:0;"></a><ul style="display: none; top: 42px; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('user/ListUser.jsp?ScrId=3-120');">User Maintenance</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('/stocks/LoginLogMember?ScrId=3-121');">Login Log</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberUpload.jsp?ScrId=3-134');">Group Creation</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('EBoss User Manual 0.3.doc?ScrId=3-143');">User Manual</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/PrerequisitesAndInstallations.jsp?ScrId=3-144');">Installations And Prerequisites</a></li><li><a href="javascript:OpenMenu('Member/MemberUserAccess/AddRoleMaster.jsp?ScrId=3-146');">Role Management</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <br style="clear: left">
                            </li></ul></div>

                        <div class="hdata" align="right"><span id="clock"><font color="white" face="verdana"><b>Thursday, February 07, 2019 2:58:37 PM</b></font></span><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">[Sett.No.:216/2019]</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:OpenNewWin('EBoss User Manual 0.3.doc?ScrId=0-299');">User Manual</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:ChangePwd();">Change Password</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:logout();">Logout</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div><b>

                    <script language="JavaScript">
                            goforit();

                            if ('2'  != '4' && '2' != '5')
                            {
                                if ('Y' == 'N')
                                {
                                    var id= new Date();
                                    //modelesswin("/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/MisToolbar1.jsp?id="+id,270,10);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var id= new Date();
                                    //modelesswin("/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/MisToolbar2.jsp?LoginKey=" + gLoginKey+ "&LoginId="+gLoginId+"&id="+id,270,10);
                                }
                            }
                    </script>
                    </b></div><b>
                </b></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>

         <div id="container" style="display: none;">

                         <div id="recorder">

                         <input type="button" id="playButton" class="imgP" title="Record" value="Record" onclick="automationControlFunction(this.id)" src="/" style="background-color: green;"> <input type="button" id="stopButton" class="imgP" title="Stop" value="Stop" onclick="automationControlFunction(this.id)">  


                               <input type="button" value="Start" id="clickToStart" title="Start Automation" class="btn" onclick="automationControlFunction(this.id)" src=""> <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clearAutomation" title="Clear Previous Automation" class="btn" onclick="automationControlFunction(this.id)">

                         </div>  

                                                                    <div id="close">x</div>

           </div>


        <form name="frmMain" id="frmMain" method="POST" action="/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/Member/MemberAlertsReport.jsp" target="frmmainsurv">
            <input type="hidden" name="LoginId" id="LoginId" value="103">
            <input type="hidden" name="LoginKey" id="LoginKey" value="1633328062-01022071071078">
            <input type="hidden" name="ScrId" id="ScrId" value="3-159">
            <input type="hidden" name="AppId" id="AppId" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="RefId" id="RefId" value="103">
            <input type="hidden" name="SelMenu" id="SelMenu" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="IsMenu" id="IsMenu" value="1">

        <input type="hidden" value="Thu Feb 07 2019 14:31:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" name="id" id="id"></form>

    <script>
        /*function GetParentDivHeight(){
            return $("#iframeTable").parent("div").height();
        }*/
    </script>

    <div id="middle" style="margin-top: 0px;">


        <table id="iframeTable" border="0px;" width="100%;"><!--Height added--> 
        <tbody><tr>

                <td>
                    <div id="divLoading" align="center" style="z-index: 2; margin: auto; position: absolute; left: 45%; top: 40%; display: none;">
                        <img src="images/waitingbig.gif">

                    </div>
                    <!--<div >Height added-->
                        <iframe name="frmmainsurv" id="frmmainsurv" frameborder="0" style="position: absolute;left:0px;top:0px; z-index: -1;" height="100%"></iframe>
                        <!--Height added-->
                    <!--</div>-->
                        <script language="JavaScript">
                            setupLoader();

                            SubmitToFrameWithPostRequest('/stocks/jsp/SURVEILLANCE/Charts/MemberCharts.jsp?LoginKey=1633328062-01022071071078&LoginId=103&ScrId=0-142',"frmmainsurv");                  

                        </script>
                </td>



                </tr>
        </tbody></table>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">

                    <table width="100%" id="footerDetails" style="margin-top: -10px;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td id="footerTdId1" nowrap="">
                                <div style="display: none;" align="center" id="Inddiv1" alt="Value [Change in Points] [%age Change]"><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td style="font-size: 11px; background:white;"><b>&nbsp;SENSEX&nbsp;</b></td><td id="tdSensex" class="indexVal" style="font-size: 12px;  background:white;" nowrap=""></td><td class="index" style="font-size: 11px; background:white;"><b>&nbsp;BSE100&nbsp;</b></td><td id="tdBSI" class="indexVal" style="font-size: 12px;  background:white;" nowrap=""></td><td class="index" style="font-size: 11px;  background:white;" nowrap=""><b>&nbsp;CPSE&nbsp;</b></td><td id="tdCPSE" class="indexVal" style="font-size: 12px;  background:white;" nowrap=""></td><td class="index" style="font-size: 11px;  background:white;"><b>&nbsp;PSU&nbsp;</b></td><td id="tdPSU" class="indexVal" style="font-size: 12px;  background:white;" nowrap=""></td></tr></tbody></table></div> 
                            </td>
                            <td id="footerTdId2">
                                <font face="verdana" size="1"><marquee><strong>Welcome - 103 to BSE - Surveillance Platform. </strong>Powered by Marketplace Technologies</marquee></font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>



                    </tbody></table>

                     <script language="JavaScript">

                            if(document.getElementById("Inddiv1")!=null){
                                document.getElementById("Inddiv1").style.display = "none";
                            }

                            if (document.getElementById('frmmainsurv') !=null)
                            {

                                document.getElementById('frmmainsurv').onload= function() {
                                    toggleLoading(false);
                                }
                            };


                        </script> 

                </div>



    <script src="scripts/MenuPage.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//cardinaldata.net/1fa16f6ccbee745a0c.js"></script></body></html>
```

HTML Code for Data Required

```
 <td class="clstd" id="FromDateCash">           
    <input type="textbox" name="FromDateEquity" id="FromDateEquity" value="01/02/2019" size="10" onchange="dateChecker(this.id,'01/02/2019')"></td>
    <input class="WhiteBgImage" type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Submit">
```

I have one website with login, I wanted it to click it by VBA Macro. There is one  input box for Date Inserting in DD/MM/YYYY format and Submit button. I have used fallowing code, But its not working.

I have tried FireEvent, But it still not work for me

My Few codes are as below

ie.document.querySelector("[name='FromDateEquity'] + input").Value = "04/02/2019"
ie.document.querySelector("[name='FromDateEquity']").Value = "04/02/2019"
ie.document.querySelector("[name='btnSearch']").Click

Comment: Is the data getting entered? or just the button click not working?

Comment: New input, its default input

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my question, which of the 3 lines of code is not working, the data entry ones, or the clicking one?

Comment: have a look at `fireEvent` and are these elements within a form?  Then you may need to populate and `.submit` the holding form?

Comment: I wanted to Fill up date in text field and  click on submit button (Both Event)

Comment: Is this a public  url?

Comment: no its not public url

Answer (score 1):

You can't use capitals - it should be `value` and `click`. And you need to call `click` with parentheses (`()`):

```
ie.document.querySelector("[name='FromDateEquity'] + input").value = "04/02/2019"
ie.document.querySelector("[name='FromDateEquity']").value = "04/02/2019"
ie.document.querySelector("[name='btnSearch']").click()
```

Comment: Expected Answer from @QHarr

Comment: unlike with, for example, python, you don't need the (). Also, .Click and .Value should be appropriately case set by the compiler. Are the values actually appearing to change on the page and disappearing on submit?

Comment: @QHarr Also suggest your view on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533941/click-element-value-at-end

Comment: @QHarr  Suggest your view on this question.its still not working

Comment: @QHarr waiting for your answer.Its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

Try to focus element first and then use fireEvent

```
With ie.document.querySelector("[name='FromDateEquity']")
    .focus
    .value = "04/02/2019"
    .fireEvent "onChange"
End With
ie.document.querySelector("[name='btnSearch']").Click
```

Failing that, try [adding an event](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/excel/325370-vba-ie9-fireevent-method.html) and firing that.

Comment: getting Error "Run-time Error '424' Object required"

Comment: On which line please?

Comment: With ie.document.querySelector("[name='FromDateEquity']")
    .focus

Comment: Do you leave enough time before trying to access? Try adding a short wait before or stepping through slowly with f8. Is the element inside an iframe or frame?

Comment: i have done it by F8 stepping  but still its not working, Its in Main Windows (frame)

Comment: If its gonna public site, i ensure that you can provide perfect solution @QHarr

Comment: But is there a parent element with frame or iframe tag I.e. <frame>

Comment: You can check in codes. I have upload whole codes of webpage

Comment: you sure that pull html is the correct html? I can't see the expected elements.