# Click Element value at end

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

System taking getelementbyid value but it allow to login if we click at that box

I wanted to log in web page "https://www.connect2nse.com/MemberPortal/home.jsp" but site takes keyboard input values only

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate "https://www.connect2nse.com/MemberPortal/home.jsp"
While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
ie.Visible = True
ie.document.getElementById("user_id").Value = "1234ABC"
ie.document.getElementById("member_code").Value = "1234"
ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = "5678"
Dim VAL As String
VAL = InputBox("Enter Captcha Value", "CAPTCHA", "")
If VAL = "" Then
End
End If
ie.document.getElementById("loginCap").Value = (VAL)
ie.document.getElementById("ext-gen39").Click
```

System enables Submit button if UserID, Member Code, Password and Captcha entered using keyboard or click on that box by mouse

How to do it by VBA

Comment: I don't know of a way to read the captcha with vba. You might try using python and [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) - _an optical character recognition (OCR) tool for python. That is, it will recognize and “read” the text embedded in images._ There are services which provide this captcha solving which you might be able to automate using vba (in terms of accessing and returning the response)

Comment: I m inserting captcha using Inputbox, But Only suggest why submit box not enable still value are there ie.document.getElementById("user_id").Value = "1234ABC"
ie.document.getElementById("member_code").Value = "1234"
ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = "5678"        it takes keyboard values ....ignore captcha part

Comment: As an aside: May I suggest you safely exit your code by using  If VAL = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
   rather than your current If statement which uses End. Also, use a proper page load wait with  While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Comment: What should i do to enable submit button?. When i enters it manually its enable, but programatically its does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to focus on the element first

```
ie.document.getElementById("loginCap").Focus
ie.document.getElementById("loginCap").Value = VAL
```

May I suggest you safely exit your code by using

```
If VAL = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
```

rather than your current `If` statement which uses `End`.

Also, use a proper page load wait with

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```